# User control in asp.net not setting the <%=value %>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control in globalsearch.aspx.

```
  <Menu:SRH id="NavSRH1" nItems="30" KeyWord="<% =ss %>" runat="server" ></Menu:SRH>
```

in globalsearch.aspx.cs i am setting the value of string "ss"

```
  public string ss = "";
  ss = Request.QueryString["q"]; //value is "Happy"
```

in the usercontrol the value of the keyword that I am getting is **<%=ss%>**, But i expect the value to be **Happy**. I was under a feeling that it will substitute the value but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx) blog tells that

> - <%# expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls. <%= expressions cannot.

And user control is more a server-side control than HTML literal, so you will have to change `"<% =ss %>"` into standard [Single-Value Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983586(v=vs.71).aspx) that could be written in a form `<%# expression %>` :

```
 "<%# ss %>"
```

Just do not forget to call [`DataBind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your code-behind (for example in the `PreRender` handler or `Page_Load` depending on your requirements)

---

Well, I am not sure what the problem is, but here is some working prototype:

Page aspx:

```
...
<Menu:SRH runat="server" id="SRH" KeyWord="<%# ss %>"/>
...
```

Page code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ss = "Happy KeyWord";
    this.DataBind();
}

public String ss;
```

User control ascx:

```
...
<asp:Panel runat="server" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"> 
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# KeyWord %>" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" ForeColor="Red"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

User control code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String text = this.KeyWord ?? "NO VALUE";
    this.label.Text = "User control load value is : " + text;
}

public String KeyWord
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

It outputs:

> Main page Happy KeyWord
>   User control load value is : Main page Happy KeyWord

**P.S.:** Also, if you use ViewState on your page then you will have to create those properties as [ViewState backed properties](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3606741/ASPNET-Tip-Create-a-ViewState-Property.htm).

Comment: How can I call in preRender method? The user control is called before the PreRender Method.

Comment: @Venkat. Hmm,in such a case perhaps I have some misconception about page lifecycle. I'll check it now.

Comment: @Venkat And just to check one moment - have you tried to call DataBind in `Page_Load`? And how do you use that value in the UserControl?

Comment: This is how I called and it has not worked.  ( protected void      Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ss = Request.QueryString["q"];
            DataBind();
        } )

Comment: @Venkat I have added some working proof of concept. If it still won't help then you will have to create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).